# Replace empty result from group stage output in mongo aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb4.0

I have a group stage in my pipeline like:

```
$group: {
  _id: null,
  count: {$sum: 1},
  results: {$push: '$$ROOT'}
}
```

Sometimes **$$ROOT** is empty and there are no results. In theses cases, I get an empty result after the group stage which is not my desired behaviour. I want to get the below object, instead with a zero count and empty results.

```
[
{
  count: 0,
  results: []
}
]
```

How can I achieve this? I tried to replace the root (by replaceRoot) but it seems when there is nothing there is no root either.

Comment: You can check the aggregation output (which is a cursor of documents), and see if it is empty. For example, `var cur = db.collection.aggregat([ ... ]); var arr = cur.toArray(); if (arr.length === 0) { printjson( { count: 0, results: [] } ) };`

Comment: @prasad_ Is there a way to handle it inside pipeline by adding some stages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- the normal way to do it i think its on the driver with simple code
- but you can also do it on the database, with more complicated code
- "empty_result" is a collection containing this
  `[{"count": 0,"results": []}]`

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6228b275c2de7b441c4b49cf)

```js
docs.aggregate(
[{"$group": 
   {"_id": null, "count": {"$sum": 1},
    "results": {"$push": "$$ROOT"}}},
 {"$unionWith": {"coll": "empty_result"}},
 {"$sort": {"count": -1}},
 {"$limit": 1}])
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems that unionWith is not supported by mongoose. Any workaround for this?

Comment: hmm, mongoose allows to write MQL as json in aggregations so i think it wont be mongoose problem(not sure thow), maybe you have old version of mongodb? union is kinda new requires MongodDB 4.4.

Comment: @_Takis I'm actually using mongo 4.4.1. with mongoose 6.0.12 and I get "TypeError: query.unionWith is not a function"

Comment: i think you are probably using the mongoose query builder(and union isnt added yet), mongoose allows us to use JSON raw, like [this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate) first example is raw JSON, the second is with the query builder.But this can be fixed using [this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate-append)  keep the query builder, and append the union stage with raw JSON. I dont use mongoose but i think you will be ok